# How to change cell format from General to Date in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, npoi

changing cell format from General to Custom datetime format but I want excel date format

How can I achieve this .Currently I am using NPOI library of C#

```
NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICellStyle dateSecondBlackCellStyle = setdateRowStyle(currentWorkBook, false);
dateSecondBlackCellStyle.DataFormat = createHelper.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy");

currentRow.GetCell(columnIndex).CellStyle = dateSecondBlackCellStyle;
currentRow.GetCell(columnIndex).CellStyle.DataFormat = dateBlackCellStyle.DataFormat;
```

I am using this code to set dataformat of datecell while generating report

Comment: Would be better if we see your work and what do you want as a result..

Comment: NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICellStyle dateSecondBlackCellStyle = setdateRowStyle(currentWorkBook, false);
                dateSecondBlackCellStyle.DataFormat = createHelper.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy");currentRow.GetCell(columnIndex).CellStyle = dateSecondBlackCellStyle;
                                                    currentRow.GetCell(columnIndex).CellStyle.DataFormat = dateBlackCellStyle.DataFormat;

Comment: Is this Window App or Web App code